# jQuery .insertAfter() and .append() not working with AJAX call

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I am trying to do something that I thought I've done 100 times already...  I'm getting and making a new image after an ajax call and am trying to insert it into an appropriate, pre-existing div

The HTML looks like this

```
<div class="preload">
    <div class="createYourOwn">...</div>
    <img src="source.com"/>
    <img src="source.com"/>
    <img src="source.com"/>
    <img src="source.com"/>
    <img src="source.com"/>
</div?
```

The AJAX call does this:

```
$.post("script.php", {phone:phone}, function(data){
    if(data){
        var newImage = "<img src='https://api.twilio.com" + data + "/>";
        $(newImage).insertAfter('.createYourOwn');
    }
});
```

I've tried this as well:

```
$("<img src='https://api.twilio.com" + data + "/>").insertAfter('.createYourOwn');
```

And this:

```
$(newImage).append('.preload');
```

even though that doesn't have the desired outcome.

I'd like to insert the image that I receive with the data just after the `.createYourOwn` div inside of `.preload`.

Not sure what's going on.  But nothing is happening, no errors, not even an image with a borked `src`.  Nothing at all happens.

Anyone have any ideas?

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Concatenate string properly:

Replace this:

```
var newImage = "<img src='https://api.twilio.com" + data + "/>";
// you're missing to close quote for src              here ^^
```

With this:

```
var newImage = "<img src='https://api.twilio.com" + data + "' />";
```

Or switch the quotes:

```
var newImage = '<img src="https://api.twilio.com' + data + '" />';
```

Comment: Aaahhh, I didn't have an end single quote on the src.  Thank you! - I can accept as answer in 9 minutes